# Change site URL in Apache with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i change my site URL using mod_rewrite my problem is when i open my site's admin section i have to write www.example.com/index.php/admin

what i want is i directly open my site like www.example.com/admin please help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `.htaccess` file copied from the [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) PHP framework:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This redirects everything that isn't `index.php`, `robots.txt` or anything in the `images` folder to `index.php/$1`, where `$1` is the URL the user entered.

You need these rules as:

- Redirecting `index.php` would cause an infinte loop - `http://localhost/index.php/index.php/index.php/...`
- `robots.txt` is an important file that search engines use. It is just plain text; you don't want it handled by your code.
- You obviously want to keep having access to your images. Adjust this path as necessary for where your static assets are located.

Comment: You rule would prevent any URL path that just *begins* with `index.php`, `images` or `robots.txt` to be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.php/ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The condition is to exclude requests of existing files to be rewritten.