# mod_rewrite, how to change the url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite:

```
domain.com/index.php/about
```

to:

```
domain.com/about
```

Comment: Which of these two URLs will be visible to the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change site URL in Apache with mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441140/change-site-url-in-apache-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule    ^about$    /index.php/about` will be the simplest one.

`RewriteRule    ^([^/]+)$    /index.php/$1` for a more generic treatment.